# Formula MAXIFS is not evaluating the full text value

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to calculate the max value of a column filtering on another column by a specific criteria.

In particular, I'm trying to evaluate the max of column F only if the column E = "2140899900040282831" (text value).

Seems that the formula is interpreting "2140899900040288378" equals to "2140899900040282831" and as a consequence returns its correspondent value (2). My expectation was to return 1.

Is there a bug in MAXIFS formula?? Seems that the algorithm is not taking the last 4 characters into consideration.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Which version of excel are you using? I suspect you are getting **2** because `MAX` function [ignores any text values](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-max-function) and the cells you are using in column `E` seem to be text cells. So the formula is just returning the highest value. [This might be an alternative](https://www.accountingweb.com/technology/excel/creating-excels-equivalent-of-maxif#:~:text=Excel%20doesn't%20have%20a,will%20do%20the%20trick%20instead.&text=Once%20you%20type%20this%20formula,return%20zero%20as%20the%20result.)

Comment: Office 365. Column E contains the criteria and not the values for which we need to calculate the "max" so in my opinion this is not the reason

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, I found below formula working on `Office365`

```
=MAX(IF(E2:E3="2140899900040282831",F2:F3,""))
```

[image]

Its also working in excel 2013 as array formula

[image]